# Use SDK (libraries, header files, etc) during creating a C++ ROS package

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, makefile, ros

I am working with Teledyne Lumenera USB Camera. I installed `lucam-sdk_2.4.3.94` for Linux on my Ubuntu 18.04. It includes these files:

[image]

The `api` folder contains this files:
[image]

One of the folders is `example` which contains several examples for working with `Teledyne Lumenera USB Camera`. Each example in `example` folder, shows one of the aspects of the camera like setting focus, reading camera info, etc. Each example has a folder that contains some `.cpp`, `.h` and one `make` file.

I want to write a C++ ROS node that uses this SDK.

First, I create a ROS package in my `catkin_ws/src` then I copy one of the examples in SDK into the `src` package folder.

When I use `catkin_make`, it says that it does not recognize `lucamapi.h`, which is one of the header files in the SDK.

My question is two parts:

1- the code that I copied from `example folders` contains some `.cpp` and `.h` files. Also, that has a `make` file beside themselves. I do not know how to handle the `make` file. How can I put parameters of the following `MakeFile` into `CMakeList.txt`?

2- I do not know how to change `CMakeList.txt` in my ROS package in order to have access to SDK headers, lib, etc.

This is `make file` for one of of the examples in the SDK:

```
#
CC = g++
LD = $(CC)

ifndef ARCH
ARCH    := $(shell uname -m | sed -e s/i.86/i386/ -e s/sun4u/sparc64/ -e s/arm.*/arm/ -e s/sa110/arm/ -e s/x86_64/x86-64/)
endif

LU_LDFLAGS = -lm -lpthread -lstdc++

PROG = livePreview
VERSION = 0.1


INCLUDES = $(LUMENERA_SDK)/include
CFLAGS = -DVERSION=\"$(VERSION)\" -I$(INCLUDES) -g
CFLAGS += -DLUMENERA_LINUX_API
OBJS = 
ALL_INCLUDES =

all lu: $(PROG)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROG) *.o *.core core *.bak *~

livePreview: verify_environment livePreview.o Camera.o
    $(LD) livePreview.o Camera.o `pkg-config --libs opencv` -llucamapi $(LU_LDFLAGS) -o $@

verify_environment:
    @if test "$(LUMENERA_SDK)" = "" ; then \
        echo "LUMENERA_SDK environment variable is not set!"; \
        exit 1; \
    fi
Camera.o: Camera.cpp $(INCLUDES)/lucamapi.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Camera.cpp 

livePreview.o: livePreview.cpp $(INCLUDES)/lucamapi.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c livePreview.cpp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Working with CMakeList and ROS was confusing.

Go to this repository, and read instalation part, then look at CMakeList.txt:

https://github.com/farhad-dalirani/lumenera_camera_package